# blank web page with d3.json(bardata.php) but works with d3.json(bardata.json)

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js

Chart is creating as it should when using d3.json(bardata.json) but the getting blank web page (no chart) when using d3.json(bardata.php)--
bardata.json is the output file from the echo of bardata.php

this is bardata.php file

```
<?php
$username = "root"; 
$password = "nk";   
$host = "localhost";
$database="homedb";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

$myquery = "
SELECT  `date`, `value` FROM  `bar_data`
";
$query = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);
?>
```

This is bardata.json

```
[{"date":"2013-01","value":"53"},{"date":"2013-02","value":"165"},{"date":"2013-03","value":"269"},{"date":"2013-04","value":"344"},{"date":"2013-05","value":"376"},{"date":"2013-06","value":"410"},{"date":"2013-07","value":"421"},{"date":"2013-08","value":"405"},{"date":"2013-09","value":"376"},{"date":"2013-10","value":"359"},{"date":"2013-11","value":"392"},{"date":"2013-12","value":"433"},{"date":"2014-01","value":"455"},{"date":"2014-02","value":"478"}]
```

And this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>

<body>

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>

<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 70, left: 40},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .05);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%m"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(10);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", 
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//getting blank web browser when passing .php output

d3.json("bardata.php", function(error, data) {

    if (error) return console.warn(error);
    console.log(data);
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
});

//if I use .json than its working, the same .json which i get by echoing the bardata.php output

/*d3.json("bardata.json", function(error, data) {

    if (error) return console.warn(error);
    console.log(data);
    data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.value = +d.value;
});*/    

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", "-.55em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)" );

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Value ($)");

svg.selectAll("bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

});

</script>

</body>
```

this library i am using is right? or what am i doing wrong? ; all files bardata.json, bardata.php, index.html are in same directory.

When debugging firefox browser getting this error at this line,
    "if (error) return console.warn(error);"

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
Stack trace:
d3_json@http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js:9488:12
respond@http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js:1939:20
```

I am new to d3.js. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show an example of the .json json and then an example of the .php json?

Comment: @Michael sorry didn't get you michael. You want me to show the output?

Comment: Based on the error you're receiving, it looks like the array `$data` isn't getting formatted correctly before you send it to json_encode. I've had this error several times and that is what it ended up being. Yes, an example of the json from both files. For example: `{"date":{"value":"1","date":"2015-10-29"}}`

Comment: And what's the json from the .php file look like?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for prompt reply, i edited the question and share my bardata.json file which is the exact output of the bardata.php( $ php bardata.php); Please can you find something wrong with its format?

Comment: What does the bardata.json output look like then? Because the json you included validates. I'm using: jsonlint.com to validate it.

Comment: Basically, it looks like it comes down to the first character. If you have a nested json then the first character should be a curly bracket `{`, but if the json isn't nested, then it should be a square bracket `[`.

Comment: @Michael To confirm, i removed square bracket from the bardaba.json and try to run index.html file with d3.json(bardata.json) than I am getting the blank web page but when again i put the square brackets than chart looks good. So can you guide me, what could be the conclusion of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93711/discussion-between-devang-and-michael).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After recreating your setup and testing it, it does load and create the bar chart without issue. I've tested it on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari and they all work. Checked the encoding to make sure it is UTF-8, so that json_encode does pick up the array. Testing with a local copy of d3.js.

Comment: this gentleman tried to help me as much as he can! and after 3 hours(yes 3!!) of continuous chat, when i thanked him, he just said 'Glad to help'; appreciate it my friend!

Comment: It was a naive one, i was double clicking on the /var/www/html/index.html instead of http://localhost/indext.html and that was the reason that browser wasn't reading php file, solved it now, thanks again for your support @Michael , it pushed me.